# Uncaught (in promise) Error: API `getFocusedTabInfo` is not currently supported in this application

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, aura

I was wondering what were the potential reasons of getting this problem, I also was wondering what are the potential solutions to solve this error.

I am using this within an aura cmp.

[image: Chrome Console]

This is where its calling from:
[image: component]

Zoomed in

[image: Component zoom]

Also am getting this right after I open up the page.

[image: Error Box]

JS File

```
        window.setTimeout(
            $A.getCallback(function() {
                var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
                workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo()
                .then(function(tabInfo) {
                    workspaceAPI.setTabLabel({tabId : tabInfo.tabId, label : 'Page'});
                    workspaceAPI.setTabIcon({tabId : tabInfo.tabId, icon : 'utility:preview'});
                });
            }), 1
        );
    }
```

Comment: Where is this aura component being called? Is it from lightning consile app or sales app etc? Can you show a screenshot or let us know that?

Comment: It's being called from the lightning console. The error is showing up within the browsers (chrome) console.

Comment: Can you share full screenshot of the page from where this is called.

Comment: Oops so sorry, Its actually in Sales app, I'll update the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Workspace api method only works in console based application. For eg: `Lightning  console` or `Service Console` . It won't work on Sales App.

From documentation:

`This component allows you to access methods for programmatically controlling workspace tabs and subtabs in a Lightning console app.`

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:workspaceAPI/documentation

Answer (score 0):

I found that, depending on what level your tab is on this error will be thrown. If its not opened on the default tab, you wont see this error.